# Two SQL queries into the same array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two database tables - one for tutors and the other for the subjects that the tutors teach.

The two are connected by the tutorID. Now I'm trying to get data from both into a single array. Is there any way to do this? I've tried doing it in sequence i.e:

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, avatar, price, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$center_lat') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('$center_lng') ) + sin( radians('$center_lat') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM users 
    having distance < '$radius' order by RAND() LIMIT 0, 20";

$result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query);

if (!$result) {
echo "Query problem";

} 
$rows = array();

//set xml header
/* header("Content-type: application/json"); */
// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($r = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$rows[] = $r;

}

$tutorID = $rows[0]['id'];

$query = "SELECT level, subject, topic
    FROM TUTORLINK
    where tutorID='$tutorID'
    order by level";

$result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query);

while ($r = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$rows[] = $r;
}

var_dump($rows);
```

but rows only contains the results of the first query - can anyone help?

Comment: Second query is likely empty. However, I guess you are actually looking for a JOIN perhaps?

Comment: Try actually nesting your loops. Not really surprising you only get the results of the first line if you explicitly query on `$rows[0]['id']`.

Comment: Read about [MySQL Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: @niels - tried that and it's not working - the problem is that the value of the element in $rows[0][id] (actually it will eventually be $rows[$i]['id'] as part of a loop) is the identifier for the tutor in the other table - so i need it to tie the subjects with the tutor

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use "union":

```
SELECT * FROM student_table UNION SELECT * FROM tutor_table
```

Comment: thanks mike - the problem is that the mapping is done by the value of $rows[0]['id'] so at the least I would need "SELECT * FROM users  UNION SELECT * FROM tutorlink where tutor_table.tutorID='$rows[0]['id']'"